# Border around a <div> element

Tags: css, html

I want to display 3 images in a row (I do not want to use tables since is not tabular data, is just one line with three images...) I have the following HTML which works OK:

```
 <div>
   <span class="step"><img src="" alt="step one" class="image" ></span>
   <span class="step"><img src="" alt="step two" class="image"></span>
   <span class="step"><img src="" alt="step three" class="image"></span>
 </div>
```

The problem starts when I add a border to each image (I also included a bit if text to describe what each image is about). I did the following in HTML,

```
 <div>
   <span class="step">First Step <img src="" alt="step one" class="image" ></span>
   <span class="step">Second Step <img src="" alt="step two" class="image"></span>
   <span class="step">Third Step <img src="" alt="step three" class="image"></span>
 </div>
```

in CSS,

```
.step{
  width:200px;
  height:150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

I was expecting to see a box with an image and a text but instead I get a bizarre box around the text only. Any ideas on how to add the border to the span element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block`. `inline` elements don't have widths or heights. `block` elements will create line breaks. Get the compromise with `inline-block`. http://caniuse.com/#feat=inline-block

If you want to support IE 6 and 7, then do inline-block on a span, instead of a div.

http://jsfiddle.net/mDHn9/

Or, as GustavoCostaDeOliveira insists, use `float: left`.

http://jsfiddle.net/6VmBj/

Comment: "inline elements don't have widths or heights." great reminder thanks!

Comment: inline-block is poorly supported, use "display:block;float:left;" instead it

Comment: @GustavoCostaDeOliveira They are goodly supported. I even added a caniuse. If you are talking about old IE, just use (my favorite) this code: `<!--[if IE]>
 <p>You are using IE &lt;10. Please update to the latest version or use <a href="http://chrome.google.com">Chrome</a></p>
<![endif]-->`

Comment: @GustavoCostaDeOliveira But I did add.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the "span" are displayed inline... Change the "span" to "div" or add display:block in css rule

Comment: If I used <div> then each image appears in each row, that is why I used <span> instead of <div>. I need the three images with a border in the same row...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `display: block;` because span is an inline by default

```
.step{
  display: block;
  width:200px;
  height:150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: The inline-block are not completely supported.. Use "block" instead it

Comment: If I add "display: block;" then the images appear one in each row. I need the three images in the same row...

Comment: @M.Froese Then use the non-well (as Gustavo.... says) supported `inline-block`or do `float:left;`

Answer (score 0):

try to add to the css

float: left;

```
.step{
  width:200px;
  height:150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NYwVd/